# Wire 2 GE smart switches to 2 different lights on the same circuit

Tags: electrical

[image: wiring image]I have 2 GE smart switches that I want to wire in the same double gang box.  1 switch is for a porch light and the other is for my interior vestibule.  There is only 1 power source in the box, and that power source will continue on to another switch elsewhere.  All wires contain a black line, white neutral, and a bare copper ground line. I understand how the power line and ground line has been jumped from one switch to the next and then out to another switch,and the load lines to the lights, but what I don't understand is the neutral lines.  Both of the smart switches have a line, a load, ground and a neutral clearly labeled.   I did wire the neutral wires using 4 way connectors.  Neutral line from hot wire, neutral from smart switch, neutral from light, and last neutral to jump to smart switch 2 in the box.  The second 4 way connector has one incoming neutral from previous 4 way, smart switch neutral, neutral from light, then an outgoing neutral to continue out to another location.

Here is the question. I powered everything up and setup my smart switches and there was light.  Although when I turn switch 1 on, both lights turn on, interior and exterior.  Likewise, when I toggle switch 2, both lights turn on/off.  When I use the GE app I installed, i can turn on light one without turning on light 2.  It's only when i physically toggle either switch that both lights turn on/off.  Did i do something wrong?

Comment: That's quite bizarre, given that your description of the neutrals shows nothing wrong.  Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Have you tried doing a factory-reset on the switches then reinitializing them?

Comment: Have not tried that, but will.  I have access to the main power line and was thinking of splitting it before I get to the switches, this way each switch would have a designated wire for power and neutral.  Do you think that would be a waste of time?  Fortunately I have a lot of time on my hands lately.

Comment: Given that the wiring inside the switch box looks rather normal, I think that messing with it further's a waste of time -- the problem's probably programming, rather than hardware

Comment: You are probably right, thanks for your time and thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue. Physically pressing the button controlled both lights, and I could use the app to control them individually. I thought it might be wiring related too.

Solution: Move one of the switches into its own 'Room' in the 'C by GE' app. Create a new Room, and assign one of the switches to the new Room (that automatically moves it out of the previous Room). Presto! Each wall switch now only controls its specific switch. This seems more like a software bug because the solution is not a logical fix, but it worked.

Thanks, Wayne